# How we can make a URL dynamic in [TestInitialize] Method in mstest, c#?

Tags: c#, mstest, winappdriver

My code is(I replace actual URL with ../../../).

```
[TestInitialize]
        public static void Initalize()
        {
            AppiumOptions desiredcap = new AppiumOptions();
            desiredcap.AddAdditionalCapability("app", @".../../../..../");
            driver = new WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723"), desiredcap);

            if (driver == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("App not running");
                return;
            }
}
```

I want to make URL dynamic of

```
desiredcap.AddAdditionalCapability("app", @".../../../..../");
```

because i want to use this method in different project. Is it possible to write variable url instead of ../../../ and take url value from some other file or from Testcase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you can create base class with `Initalize(string capUrl)` method and call it in derived classes as here:

```
    [TestInitialize]
    public static void Initalize()
    {
        base.Initalize("http://SomeUri.com")
    }
```

If you need to specify it in Testcase. Then you need to remove `[TestInitialize]` and it's better to rename it  to something like "PrepareTest". And call it by hands in test method. Like this:

```
[Testcase("http://SomeUri.com")]
public void TestMethod(string uri)
{
    this.PrepareTest(uri);
}
```

Is this solution helps you? Or you need something other?

Comment: So we cannot pass URL variable directly in [TestIntialize] Method.???

Comment: No. TestInitialize should setup things that common for all tests. In your case you can use DataDrivenTest (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/how-to-create-a-data-driven-unit-test?view=vs-2015&redirectedfrom=MSDN) or TestContext (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcontext?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=mstest-net-1.2.0)

Comment: But I recomend you to use separate classes that extends base class. Then you will split a lot of tests to different groups and split it to different files.

Comment: I get you. Now i have used SetURL and GetURL property and use this properties in My [TestInitialize] Method.